# Public data and examples for practicing distribution fitting?

Tags: references, learning

Are there public data for practicing distribution fitting and examples? I want to practice parameter estimation with various methods. To do so it would be helpful if there are reliable examples of fitting models to the data so that I can crosscheck if my estimations are correct, the same way as how people study using 'problems and solutions' books.

It seems there are blog postings, but many of those don't look very helpful for serious studies. Many of them talk about trivial, overly simplified data. Typical, the authors assume that there's only one parameter to fit. Also, often the programs are not optimized to have a good accuracy but made for illustration.

It would be great if you could share resources for more serious real-word practices which deal with more than two, correlated parameters. Also having many different datasets to study various problems would be great.

Comment: Almost dups:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16130/datasets-for-data-visualization-examples-teaching-and-research https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I asked for much more specific resources..  real-world data with serious analysis examples or at least serious fitting results. Also, the subject is distribution fitting, but not all the statistical problems.

Comment: This is close to off-topic here, so might be closed. I would start looking in R packages. I will see if I can write an answer based on such.